# Reading the attribute of a custom SharePoint column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, site-column

In my SP project, I created a custom Site Column (just plain text type), with one Custom Setting option (FieldEditorUserControl, also a text). What I want to achieve is, when I have a custom list which I have added my site column to, I want it to be automatically set to the value of the custom property. In other words:

1. I create the site column of my custom type, setting my custom attribute of the column to, for example "Lemon cake"
2. I create a custom list in my SharePoint site and next I add my custom column from the existing site columns
3. At last, when I add new ListItem to my list, I want my field that belongs to the custom column to be set to a value of my custom attribute, so after adding new item, the value of my custom column in this item equals "Lemon cake"

Any hint would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried default value?

Comment: Default value would be easy but I want the user to be able to put the information on column creation and what is more, the value from the attribute is meant to be the part of a string that will finally land in this field value.